# How to do a lookup in excel with VBA then change the cell contents?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using `VLOOKUP` to find a specific value that corresponds to a property of a unique `ID` ie. using it to lookup the cost of a unique item ID:

```
ID  Cost
----------
A   $12    
B   $16
```

How can I do a ID lookup and then modify the contents of the cell instead of just reading what corresponds to it?

Answer (score 1):

Use MATCH to return the row number within the Lookup Range. Then you can change required cell on that row using OFFSET or (better) INDEX.